# Issue with componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
 void componentWillReceiveProps(
  object nextProps
)
```

This is what official documentation says => Invoked when a component is receiving new props. **This method is not called for the initial render.**

I am rendering a component with props like below in the parent component -

```
<ArticleDetails articleDetails={this.state.details}></ArticleDetails>
```

ArticleDetails component has componentWillReceiveProps method defined. According to documentation it should not get called when I refresh the page(initial render), but it does. If the reason is because I am passing props on first call itself, then is there any way that you could render it first time without passing props and then somehow pass props later?

```
var ArticleDetails = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {author: '', tags: '', data:'', relatedArticles:{}};
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps :function(){
    console.log("i am called");
    this.setState({tags:this.props.articleDetails._id||''})
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   /// do something
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="articleForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Your name"
          value={this.state.heading}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Say something..."
          value={this.state.tags}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: it shouldn't be invoked, maybe something makes changes or props right after the first render?

Comment: `One common mistake is for code executed during this lifecycle method to assume that props have changed.` - from the same docs

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/01/08/A-implies-B-does-not-imply-B-implies-A.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link @havenchyk , Figured out the issue after reading the article. I was updating the state for another component in parent, at the time of doing it, it must have been passing the same state values again for ArticleDetails component too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're not using componentWillReceiveProps correctly.  The method gets passed next props.  Using this.props inside of that method will give you the previous props.  E.g. (in pseudo code)

```
input field initial props = Hi 
input field update to props = Hi! 
nextProps = Hi!
this.props = Hi
```

I don't think you'll be too happy with your code structure long term.  Using props to set state is considered an anti pattern.  https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Why not use the props directly?

```
<input
   type="text"
   placeholder="Say something..."
   value={this.props.tags}
 />
```

I would do it this way...

http://jsbin.com/sojaju/edit?js,output

```
var Article = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { tags : 'Sports, Football'};
    },
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { value } = e.target;
        this.setState({ tags: value });
        // send to server
    },
    handleTagChange(e) {
        const { value } = e.target;
        this.setState({ tags: value });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <ArticleDetails 
                articleDetails={this.state.tags}
                handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} 
                handleTagChange={this.handleTagChange}
            />
            );
    }
});

var ArticleDetails = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
        const { handleTagChange, articleDetails } = this.props;
    return (
      <form className="articleForm" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Say something..."
                    onChange={handleTagChange}
          value={articleDetails}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Article />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Thanks D.Walsh what you are saying, it does make sense. One question though.? So If a component doesn't have have any child(nested) components, in that case it should never use 'state' instead it should use props directly, is that what you are trying to suggest? Or there could be a use case where we might need to use state in component, even if that component doesn't have any child components?

Answer (score 0):

In Article details I was passing this.state.details through props

```
<ArticleDetails articleDetails={this.state.details}></ArticleDetails>
```

But when I update state in parent for another component by updating this.state.somethingdifferent In that case It passes same props values again for all the remaining components. Thats why componentWillReceiveProps was getting triggered.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/01/08/A-implies-B-does-not-imply-B-implies-A.html